# Why did English start verbalizing Latin past participles, not keep nativizing infinitive suffixes like it used to do to French verbs?

Tags: verbs, latin, historical-change, loanwords, french

The way English adapted French verbs used to be quite straightforward: swap the French infinitive suffixes with Middle English *-en*:

- Latin *crīd**āre*** > Old French *cri**er*** > Middle English *cri**en*** (13th century) > Modern English *cry*
- Latin *fīn**īre*** > Old French *fin**ir*** (present participle *fin**issant***) > Middle English *fin**ishen*** (14th century) > Modern English *fin**ish*** (admittedly, it was not at all straightforward with these *-ir* verbs)
- Latin *frīg**ere*** > Old French *fri**re*** > Middle English *fry**en*** (13th century) > Modern English *fry*

But for some weird reason, English used a different approach with later Latin borrowings: just verbalize the past participles and do away with infinitives altogether.

- Latin *dict**ātus*** (infinitive *dict**āre***) > English *dict**ate*** (16th century)
- Latin *ign**ītus*** (infinitive *ign**īre***) > English *ign**ite*** (16th century)
- Latin *īnflīc**tus*** (infinitive *īnflīg**ere***) > English *inflic**t*** (16th century)

And there are cases where English did one way, then changed it minds later, probably without even consulting French:

- Latin *cōnstru**ere*** > Middle English *constru**en*** (14th century) > English *constru**e***
- Latin *cōnstrū**ctus*** > English *constru**ct*** (17th century)

Was there a good reason that justifies the newer approach? Why didn't English use the older way to potentially make verbs like **dict*, **ignish* or **infly*?

Comment: Is it because some came through Old French (in the Anglo-Norman era) and the later ones directly from Latin?

Comment: @StuartF That doesn't really have any explanatory power, and is already what I express with this question. Also, in the case of *cōnstruere* which ended up as both *construe* (old way, 14th century) and *construct* (new way, 15th century), even though no source (Online Etymology Dictionary and Oxford English Dictionary) I know even mentions Old French, it seems plausible that Middle English speakers were cognizant enough to apply the old French way to newer Latin words. At one point, at least. In the span of barely a century, something must have happened to trigger such a paradigm shift.

Comment: @StuartF Pardon the mistake, *construct* dates back to the 17th century

Comment: Asking "why" about language change is mostly fruitless. While there are some general patterns, and you can identify when a change conforms to a pattern (e.g. the Great Vowel Shift), there are lots of exceptions with little rhyme or reason. Languages are like clothing styles, they change with the whims of the speakers.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the principal difference is that the Latinate forms were adopted into English by scholarly men who read and wrote in Latin, while the Middle English forms were adopted by people who were much less conversant in Latin but spoke some French.;

Comment: @Barmar I've asked fruitless why questions before and I still think they're worth asking. Better than not asking at all.